Equality by definition symbol
Since when is the symbol $x := y$ (for "$x = y$ by definition") used in mathematics?

Used in computer programming. See this post as well as this one

I'm looking for the history of this symbol.

Basically, was not used in math prior to the diffusion of programming languages during the '50s.

The $:=$ symbol was imported from programming languages, but the practice of symbolically distinguishing definitional equalities is older. Peano placed $\text{Def}$ at the end of definitional equalities in his Formulario (1894, although not consistently, see Grattan-Guiness), and Russell and Whitehead wrote $=\text{Df}$ in  Principia (1910), p.9. Variants like $\stackrel{\text{def}}=$ and $=_{def}$ are still used.

@Conifold What is the difference between = and := in mathematics? The first indicates quantitative equality, the second indicates definition, the left hand side is defined as the right hand side. Is this correct?

Cf. this question on Math SE, where comment suggested posting here

@zeynel Yes, that is the 'proper' use, but some authors just write = in both cases.

A colleague uses a =:   symbol to mean, "which we define to be", as a way of introducing new notations.  As in $\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}=:|x|$.

Besides the alternatives that @Conifold enumerated, you’ll sometimes also see $\stackrel{\Delta}{=}$, where the delta stands for define (or for one of its Latin predecessors).
